# Custom UITextView scroll size

Tags: xcode, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview, xcode6

I have UITextView, and I insert attributed text with a lot of image. When I scroll It has a lot of lag in first scroll. I found that it estimate size of scroll wrong. For example when attributed string loaded to UITextView content size is 2534 but when I scroll down It change to 7439. I have a method that predict content size but when I set it not works:

```
self.textView.contentSize.height = 7439
```

But it not take effect! How should I write custom class derived from UITextView which handle content size with my custom function?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why but I found this:

```
self.textView.layoutManager.allowsNonContiguousLayout = false
```

This will solve problem!